# np.isin() returning duplicate results

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to filter out duplicates by comparing a dataframe against a np.array. 
With `user_id=1` it filters correctly. However `user_id=8` it gives me duplicates. Why?

My np.array usedUserArticlesIds =

```
array([[1202623831,          1]], dtype=int64)
```

My DataFrame dfUserArticles:

```
user_id article_id  date_saved
2   1   1202623831  2019-05-09 10:46:20
23  1   1127087222  2019-01-03 21:33:46
31  8   823279599   2019-05-20 13:42:16
32  8   327321877   2019-05-20 13:42:16
33  8   590862779   2019-05-20 13:42:15
34  8   2341781293  2019-05-20 13:41:55
```

`dfUserArticles = dfUserArticles[~np.isin(dfUserArticles[['user_id', 'article_id']], usedUserArticlesIds)]`

Output:

```
    user_id article_id  date_saved
23  1   1127087222  2019-01-03 21:33:46
31  8   823279599   2019-05-20 13:42:16
31  8   823279599   2019-05-20 13:42:16
32  8   327321877   2019-05-20 13:42:16
32  8   327321877   2019-05-20 13:42:16
33  8   590862779   2019-05-20 13:42:15
33  8   590862779   2019-05-20 13:42:15
34  8   2341781293  2019-05-20 13:41:55
34  8   2341781293  2019-05-20 13:41:55
```

Expected output:

```
user_id article_id  date_saved
23  1   1127087222  2019-01-03 21:33:46
31  8   823279599   2019-05-20 13:42:16
32  8   327321877   2019-05-20 13:42:16
33  8   590862779   2019-05-20 13:42:15
34  8   2341781293  2019-05-20 13:41:55
```

Comment: Please explain what you expect to happen and provide sample output.

Comment: @WoodyPride Edited my question slightly and provided expected sample output

Comment: You need to use `loc` for Boolean filtering, i.e. `dfUserArticles = dfUserArticles.loc[some_Boolean_array]`.

Comment: @jpp This gives me ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

Comment: @SomeName, Then make sure you `np.isin` returns a 1-dimensional Boolean array (it likely does not the way you've defined it).

Comment: @jpp It does indeed not because I have multiple rows and 2 values.

Comment: You need to add an `.all(1)`: `~(np.isin(df[['user_id', 'article_id']], usedUserArticlesIds).all(1))`

Comment: @ALollz Perfect! Thank you so much. Can you explain why all(1) fixed it?